# How to read C# object from Azure service bus message in Python

Tags: c#, python, azure, message-queue, azureservicebus

I am currently trying  to determine the message contents from a message that I get from the azure service bus. However, the content is an object which I suspect is written in C#.

```
<uamqp.c_uamqp.cMessage object at 0x00000000033B3810>
```

I am currently using python and I would like to access this object and obtain its attributes. Is there any way about doing this?

EDIT: 
This is just the attributes that is contained in one message object

```
{'auto_renew_error': None, 
'_encoding': 'UTF-8', 
'_expiry': None, 
'received_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 8, 13, 21, 39,
405000), 
'_receiver': <azure.servicebus.receive_handler.Receiver object at 0x00000000033A47F0>, 
'_annotations': {'x-opt-enqueued-time': 1565284860716L, 'x-opt-enqueue-sequence-number': 0L, 'x-opt-locked-until': 1565284959471L, 'x-opt-sequence-number': 3406L},
'header': <uamqp.message.MessageHeader object at 0x00000000039BE400>, 
'_app_properties': None, 
'message': <uamqp.message.Message object at 0x00000000039BE320>, 
'properties': <uamqp.message.MessageProperties object at 0x00000000039BE2E8>}
```

```
def getAttribute(message):
        print(message.__dict__['message'].__dict__['_message'])
```

Code above basically just takes message object, then read its attributes, and keeps on viewing attributes of objects which are embedded in the initial message object. I am stuck on the '_messages' object as I cannot read its attributes with .**dict**

Comment: Can you please share the code for how you received the uamqp message? Also, please check the link to use the v7 to receive messages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues

Answer (score 0):

Even if the object is created in C# it should still be serialized properly and read without issues. You'll need to decode the body and parse the JSON message.

```py
while True:
    msg = bus_service.receive_subscription_message(config.topic, config.subscription, peek_lock=True)

    if msg.body is None:
        print('No messages')
        continue

     print(json.loads(msg.body.decode("utf-8")))
```

Can you provide more code showing your approach and where you are getting that result?

Comment: Hey Kurtis. I updated the code, hopefully it will give a bit more context